# Limitar valor do Input

Tags: javascript, html, css

Olá,

tenho um *input* chamado gasto, e o valor digitado não pode ser *maior que **1.000,00***, se for *maior que **1.000,00*** aparece um *modal* na tela.

Poderiam me ajudar em como fazer esse javascript, por favor?

Comment: Conhece o atributo `max`? E o que sabe de javascript? Já tentou fazer alguma coisa? Qual foi a dificuldade?

Comment: sim, não quero fazer com max. Eu tinha feito um script, porem apaguei pois estava dando muito erro

Comment: a ideia seria a pessoa digitar 1000,00 no campo e clicar no botão botão calcular, e ele aparecer a mensagem, apenas um alert depois eu me viro aqui

Comment: Poderia descrever como fez na pergunta? Dê-nos uma base de do que sabe, de qual foi sua dificuldade, de quais erros deram, etc. Da forma que está, parece que está pedindo que façamos para você. Por que não quer usar `max`?

Comment: Ola carlos, o script é esse https://jsfiddle.net/4npemgvq/

Comment: Edição da pergunta revertida pois a "nova" pergunta é completamente diferente da original, invalidando todas as respostas atuais.

Comment: Você deve usar event.preventDefault() pra impedir o submit, e utilizar o submit do form ao invés do click do botão https://jsfiddle.net/7kr1g4md/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> nesse `if($('#gasto').val() >= 1000.00){` deixe o valor como numérico
>
> se a entrada no input for com virgula, tem que trocar a virgula por ponto para poder fazer comparação

```js
$(function() {
  $(".btn-gasto").click(function() {
         if($('#gasto').val() >= 1000.00){
              //alert('Para o seu consumo iremos tratar o seu orçamento e projeto de forma exclusiva. ');
              $("#myModal").modal('show');
              event.preventDefault();
                    
         } else{
             alert('menor que 1000.');
         }

  });
 return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<form name="calculadora" method='post' action='https://www.sunkit.com.br/resultado/'>
<input type="tel" id="gasto" name="gasto" placeholder="R$ 0.00" required>

<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-gasto">Calcular</button>
</form>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
           <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
               <h4 class="modal-title">Consumo acima de R$1000.00 </h4>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-body">
               <p>Para o seu consumo iremos tratar o seu orçamento e projeto de forma exclusiva.</p>
             </div>
             <div class="modal-footer">
               <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
             </div>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

> O método `preventDefault`, que como o nome já dá ideia, previne o comportamento default do objeto, ou seja cancela o comportamento que os elementos geralmente tem na página, então, nesse caso, evita que o clique do botão submeta o formulário

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o `addEventListener()`, a partir daí pode pegar o valor e fazer a verificação:

```js
INPUT_OBJECT.addEventListener('input', function (evento) {
     alert(this.value);
});
```

Qualquer dúvida estou a disposição!

Fonte: [Pure JavaScript listen to input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946235/pure-javascript-listen-to-input-value-change)

Answer (score 1):

Há uma solução simples e fácil para o seu problema, utilizando apenas *html5*.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
<input type="number" required="true" name="price" min="0" max="1000.00" step=".01"> 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Explicação das tags**

1. required: Reforça que o elemento seja preenchido.
2. (min/max): Use o atributo min junto com o atributo max para criar um intervalo de valores permitidos.
3. step: O atributo step especifica os intervalos numéricos legais para um elemento .
   se step = "3", os números legais podem ser -3, 0, 3, 6, etc. No nosso caso: **.01** para permitir valores decimais.

Caso você queira que o seu input tenha valores negativos, basta remover o atributo *min*.

Espero ter ajudado e bem vindo ao stackoverflow!